# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'login'

Tags: python, gspread

```
import gspread  
gc = gspread.login(‘the.email.address@gmail.com’,’password’)
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'login'

Comment: What is gspread? And what makes you think it has a 'login' attribute? If it's [this](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), it doesn't.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) properly next time!!, `gspread` obviosly does not have a login method perhaps what you are looking for is the `authorize()` method

Comment: but I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/

Comment: @Gizvo: If you use outdated documentation you should use an outdated version of the package. The better idea would be to use the current version of the package and to use up-to-date documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The [`gsspread`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) that I know of doesn't have the `login` method!

I guess what you are looking for is `authorize`.

You would ideally do something like this:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials) # check link below on how to obtain the credentials
```

The procedure on how to obtain the `credentials` is very well documented by gsspread here - http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html